# Show Publisher documents using object tag

Tags: html, object-tag

How can we show Publisher(.pub) documents using object tag in HTML. I was able to add this success fully for a pdf file by adding a type attribute as shown below,

```
<object height="100%" width="100%" type="application/pdf" data="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**To show Publisher files directly, you would need some kind of browser extension**. These exist for PDF, which is probably how you made PDF work so easily, though some browsers have taken to building in native PDF support as well. But no browser maker has built in support like this for Publisher documents, and I'm not aware of any add-ons for Publisher documents either. Even Microsoft doesn't make one.

**However, you could export these Publisher documents to some other format, and then show those**. HTML would be easiest for browsers to support, though options exist for PDF (which browsers can then support via plug-ins or their own built-in support).